# How does jquery qtip make its arrows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, qtip

qtip is not using images to make its arrows, like other tips out there. So I was wondering how they are making their dynamic arrow tip?

A person can easily change the size of the tip with width/height.

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#tips

Comment: it also works in ie6, so canvas dont work in ie6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They use (at least) 2 different technologies (depending on the browser):

- **[Vector Markup Language (VML)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language)** for **Internet Explorer**.
- **[Canvas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canvas_element)** for **Google Chrome** and **Firefox**.

Answer (score 0):

They're using an html5 canvas

```
<div class="qtip-tip" . . .>
    <canvas height="12" width="12"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are using [CSS Triangles](http://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles), as they seem to work in non html-5 compliant browsers.

Comment: No, I don't think so. You can check the source code of the page to see that they are not using `border` as CSS Triangles do. They just use VML in IE and Canvas in the rest.